# Excel 2013 VBA Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm currently working on a Excel file and added some VBA. I added a button on Sheet1 with the following VBA:

```
Sub AddRow()
Dim c, d As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A100")
For dblCounter = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set c = rng(dblCounter)
   If c.Value Like "XXXXXX" Then
        c.EntireRow.Insert
        For dblCounter2 = rng2.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set d = rng2(dblCounter2)
        If d.Value Like "YYYYYY" Then
        d.EntireRow.Insert
        End If
        Next dblCounter2
    End If
Next dblCounter
End Sub
```

The purpose of the code is to add a new row on Sheet1 above the cell containing "XXXXXX" and a new row on Sheet2 above the cell containing "YYYYYY". Adding a new row on Sheet1 works. However, adding a new row on Sheet2 doesn't. I get a 'Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch' error at `If d.Value Like "YYYYYY" Then` but no error at `If c.Value Like "XXXXXX" Then` and i don't know why. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the cell that is being tested. is the value an error?

Comment: is it possible the "YYYYY" does not exist in the 2nd sheet?

Comment: `d` is holding 100 cells? Can you `if` 100 cells at a time?

Comment: @findwindow d is only one cell.  OP is looping through the range.

Comment: I just copied this code into a new blank workbook and it works fine for me, the error may be in the sheet not the code

Comment: Why not use something like ..... `rows(match("XXXXXX",sheet1!a1:a100,0)).insert`  I've not tested, but would only be 1 line, you can make it recursive, until it runs out of matches also...... maybe

Comment: is it only 1 instance per button click, or are there multiple instances of `XXXXXX` and / or `YYYYYY`?

Comment: there's only one instance of `XXXXXX` or `YYYYYY`. I'm looping through the range until the cell value matches `XXXXXX` respectively `YYYYYY` and then the row is added. The error is probably in the sheet and not the code. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
                If d.Value Like "YYYYYY" Then
                    d.EntireRow.Insert
                End If
```

to this

```
If Not IsError(d.Value) Then
   If d.Value Like "YYYYYY" Then d.EntireRow.Insert
End If
```